# batch ftp hanging on get

Tags: batch-file, command-line, ftp

Hi am trying to write an MS Dos batch file that logs into an ftp server, and downloads a file

The ftp is hosted in IIS, but it is not directly under my control (3rd party).

my script is as follows (filename ftpcmd.dat)

```
user bob
mypassword
get /foldrname/export.txt c:\export.txt 
quit
```

and it then gets executed like this

```
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat ftp.myserver.co.za
```

The problem is that it always gets stuck on the get command, ftp responds like this

```
501 Server cannot accept argument.
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection.
```

I have tried doing this manually on command prompt, exact same result.

I can do this using a tool like FileZilla, one thing I noticed is that it switches to Passive Mode, so to emulate this i tried adding this after logging in

```
quote pasv
```

This switches to passive mode, but the same problem persists.

note - I cant get the service provider to make any config changes.
Also note - it works perfectly using filezilla client

Thanks!

Comment: did you try to get the file with some other tools? like wget for example:
`wget ftp://user:password@ftp.myserver.co.za/foldrname/export.txt`

alternatively you could get wireshark, and sniff on exact commands that filezilla sends. then just place them in ftpcmd.dat

also a note: last time i used a ftp script it went sth like this:
`open ftp.server.com
user
password
...
disconnect
bye`

Comment: wiresharks output is a bit beyond me. i can look at wget, but then my next function is going to be to delete a file, and then put, which i think are both out of the scope of wget ?

Comment: what about changing folder before `get` command? like: `cd foldername` and afterwards `get export.txt`

Comment: Tried that also.  No luck.  I am trying out Curl instead now

Answer (score 0):

I think this is basically part of what @rostok says, but typically I would use

```
user bob mypassword
get /foldrname/export.txt c:\export.txt 
quit
```

You could also just invoke it with

```
open ftp.myserver.co.za
user bob mypassword
get /foldrname/export.txt c:\export.txt 
quit
```

Be sure the foldrname is really off the root.  What happens if you

```
cd foldrname
```

Does that give an error?  Does `cd \foldrname` work or give an error?  Can you successfully use `lcd c:\export.txt?`  Might just be a path issue.

Be sure to try it manually before creating a script so you can tell exactly what's happening at each step.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script:

```
open ftp.myserver.co.za
bob
mypassword
binary
lcd "c:\"
get /foldrname/export.txt 
quit
```

Execute it like this:

```
ftp -i -s:ftpcmd.dat
```

Note that you need permissions to write to **c:\**